# Почему не подгружаеться CSS, JS и прочее?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Например в конроллере где метод начинаеться вот так:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class AdminController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginPage(Model model){
```

Всё впорядке. Всё подгружаеться как следует и путь к css: components/css/... считывает нормально. Но когда метод такой:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/image/{image_name}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String imagePage(@PathVariable("image_name") String image_name,Model model){
    ...
    return "image";
}
```

То путь к CSS он видит как image/components/css/... И следовательно CSS не подгружаются

Comment: Хорошо бы увидеть как вы ссылку на CSS файл во view делаете.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/site.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/icon.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/search.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/senantic_min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/custom/other.css">

Comment: Помогла запись /path/to/css

Comment: Запостил как ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один из вариантов, это сделать все пути абсолютными -- `components/site.css` -> `/components/site.css` Но, если приложение будет "загружено" в context path отличный от `/`, то ссылки перестануть быть валидными.

Ещё вариант -- попробовать ислользовать хэлперы `<spring:url>` (JSP) либо `th:href="@{/path/to/css}"` (Thymeleaf).